# How to implement multiple file upload in Django

Tags: django, image, file-upload, upload

How to implement multiple file upload in Django with two models?
I have 1 form but two models that make two forms

models.py

```
class Ads(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=85, blank=False)

class Images(models.Model):
    ad = models.ForeignKey(Ads, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to='')
    thumbnail = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

views.py

```
class CreateAd(CreateView):
    model = Ads
    form_class = CreateAdForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('index')
```

forms.py

```
class CreateAdForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Ads
        fields = ('title',)

class ImageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Images
        fields = ('image', )
```

Comment: Add an image field to your `CreateAdForm` that takes multiple file input, then in the `CreateView`'s `form_valid()` method, create each `Image`. So basically only use one form (ditch the `ImageForm`) and follow the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/file-uploads/#handling-uploaded-files-with-a-model) to create the models from the uploaded files.

Comment: I tried it,  but the image field can have only one file. I tried to add attribute multiple,  but it doesn't upload multiple images.

Comment: I found in django documentation multiple images upload.  But how do I set like thumbnail to first image, or is it better to make separate file upload input for thumbnail image?

Comment: You can’t control the order in which the files are uploaded so if the images are supposed to be used differently, then you should use separate image fields.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are looking for [django formset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/)

formset is a layer of abstraction to work with multiple forms on the same page.

Comment: I don't think a formset is useful here. It would be if you add images with extra information, but I think OP just wants to upload multiple images at once and for this one file input field with multiple set works without having to resort to a formset.

Comment: No, I have two models. Basically, I have form with post model and image model in one form request. So one post can have multiple images. Image db has a foreign key to post, so images are a child to post.